# Json validation using patternProperties does now work

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I use the Github library ["json-schema"](https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema) to validate JSON against a custom schema. But I am having trouble validating the following JSON against my defined schema.

JSON holding 2 news entries:

```
[{
  "bodytext": "Lorem ipsum",
  "datetime": "2018-01-29T13:18:56+0100",
  "falMedia": {
    "00000000519602e500007f310096b8e2": {
      "alternative": null,
      "description": "The description",
      "link": "",
      "pid": 6043,
      "processedFile": {
        "publicUrl": "image01.png"
      },
      "title": null,
      "uid": 52925
    },
    "0000000051960a1700007f310096b8e2": {
      "alternative": null,
      "description": "Another description",
      "link": "",
      "pid": 6043,
      "processedFile": {
        "publicUrl": "images/picture01.jpg"
      },
      "title": null,
      "uid": 52927
    }
  },
  "falRelatedFiles": [ ],
  "istopnews": true,
  "pid": 6043,
  "teaser": "A short lorem teaser",
  "title": "The message title",
  "uid": 51911
},
{
  "bodytext": "Hello World",
  "datetime": "2018-01-29T13:24:33+0100",
  "falMedia": [ ],
  "falRelatedFiles": [ ],
  "istopnews": false,
  "pid": 339,
  "teaser": null,
  "title": "Just a short message",
  "uid": 51915
}]
```

This is my schema against which I try to validate:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
  "title": "FPÖ News",
  "description": "Schema for FPÖ News articles accesed by the mobile apps",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "bodytext": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "datetime": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "falMedia": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "type": "object",
            "patternProperties": {
              "^[0-9abcde]*$": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "alternative": {
                    "type": ["null", "string"]
                  },
                  "description": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "link": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "pid": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "processedFile": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "additionalProperties": false,
                      "publicUrl": {
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "title": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "uid": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  }
                },
                "additionalProperties": false
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "array"
          }
        ]

      },
      "falRelatedFiles": {
        "type": "array"
      },
      "istopnews": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "pid": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "teaser": {
        "type": ["string", "null"]
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "uid": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "bodytext",
      "datetime",
      "istopnews",
      "pid",
      "teaser",
      "title",
      "uid"
    ]
  }
}
```

It seems to me that everything underneath the part "patternProperties" is not concidered when validating.

My issue is, that the keys for the objects underneath "falMedia" are generated dynamically. Therefore I do not know these values. I thought about using the "patternProperties". But when I change the values of the "falMedia" entries in the "news" to something which (according to the supplied regex under patternProperties) is not valid, the library still says that everything is fine.

Am I missing out on something here? 
Is my schema false?

I would greatly appriciate any help.

Thanks
Klaus

Comment: I would suggest removing information not relevant to the question, as it's quite a lot of JSON to parse through to find what you're asking about. If I understood correctly, what you'll want to keep are the `falMedia` fields and the schema relating to that field.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that your regex should be "^[0-9abcdef]*$" instead of "^[0-9abcde]*$". Because you're missing the "f", `patternProperties` doesn't match any of the values and therefore doesn't constraint the properties in "falMedia".

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will check back with this.